# Why validate function is not called in Rails3.2.9?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

The codes are as follows:

```
class Seat < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :baggage, :flight_id, :name
  def validate(record)
    errors.add_to_base("You have too much baggage")
  end
end
```

I expected it throws error whenever a new record is wriiten into the database.

However, nothing happened when new record wriiten into `seats` database by `@seat.save`

Does anyone have ideas about this?

Comment: Did you try without the record parameter (`def validate ... end`)? Also, I believe the add_to_base is [deprecated](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Errors/add_to_base) for rails 3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`validate(record)` looks weird. You should try

```
class Seat < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :baggage, :flight_id, :name
  validate :valid_baggage

  def valid_baggage
    errors.add_to_base("You have too much baggage")
  end
end
```

Also note that you need to call `@seat.save!` (instead of `@seat.save`) in order to get the exception.  `@seat.save` will return true or false only ... but that's usually what you want, so consider if you really want to raise an exception.

Answer (score 0):

The record parameter is only needed if you are implementing a [custom validator](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#validates_with), otherwise the method already knows which record it is validating (self).